# Get Weekdayname from custom date

Tags: macros, xstring, date

I'm new to LaTeX and need help.

I want to convert a input of this date format: `20161027` to this output:
"Thursday, 27.10.2016"

I tried around with the packages `xstring` and `datenumber`.

The following code runs into an error.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datenumber}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.50cm, top=6.50cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\shortdat}{\datedayname {,} \thedateday.\thedatemonth.\thedateyear}
\newcommand{\stringtosub}{\nul}
\newcommand{\substring}[2][1]{
    \ifx\\#2\\
    {\stringtosub}
    \else
    \StrMid{\stringtosub}{#1}{#2}
    \fi
}
    \newcommand{\operation}[1]{
    \renewcommand{\stringtosub}{#1}
    \substring[1]{4}.\substring[5]{6}.\substring[7]{8}
    \setdate{\substring[1]{4}}{\substring[5]{6}}{\substring[7]{8}}
    \shortdat
}

\begin{document}
    first \operation{20161025}
    \\
    next \operation{20161027}
\end{document}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I haven't used the package myself so far, but from my mind I'd say that the `datetime2` package from Nicola Talbot could do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using [`datetime2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[calc,english]{datetime2}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\operation}[1]{\@operation #1\relax}
\def\@operation #1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8\relax{{%
  \DTMsavedate{saveddate}{#1#2#3#4-#5#6-#7#8}%
  \DTMsetdatestyle{mydate}% Set new date style
  \DTMusedate{saveddate}% Set date
}}
\DTMnewdatestyle{mydate}{%
  % #1 = year
  % #2 = month
  % #3 = day
  % #4 = day of week
  \renewcommand{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{%
    \DTMweekdayname{##4}, \DTMtwodigits{##3}.\DTMtwodigits{##2}.\number##1}%
}

\begin{document}

first \operation{20161025}

next \operation{20161027}

\end{document}
```

The implementation assumes that your input for `\operation` will always be of the form `YYYYMMDD` (in other words, two-digit representations for the month and day).

Answer (score 2):

It's much simpler: just absorb the digits as macro arguments.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datenumber}

\newcommand{\operation}[1]{\splitdate#1}
\newcommand{\splitdate}[8]{%
  \begingroup % to keep \setdate local
  \setdate{#1#2#3#4}{#5#6}{#7#8}%
  \datedayname,~#7#8.#5#6.#1#2#3#4%
  % if you want to omit leading zeros use the line below
  %\datedayname,~\number#7#8.\number#5#6.#1#2#3#4%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

first \operation{20161025}

next \operation{20161027}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also want to check the length of the argument to be eight characters, you can do as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datenumber}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\operation}{m}
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \tl_count:n { #1 } = 8 }
   {
    \crss_print_date:nnnnnnnn #1
   }
   {
    \errmessage{Invalid~date}
    ERR-#1-ERR
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \crss_print_date:nnnnnnnn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \setdate{#1#2#3#4}{#5#6}{#7#8}
  \datedayname,~#7#8.#5#6.#1#2#3#4
  % if you want to omit leading zeros use the line below
  %\datedayname,~\number#7#8.\number#5#6.#1#2#3#4
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

first \operation{20161025}

next \operation{20161027}

error \operation{1233}

error \operation{123456789}

\end{document}
```

Invalid values of month and day will be signalled by `datenumber`.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't Werner's code also absorb them as macro arguments? Do you mean that yours is simpler because they are absorbed directly?

Comment: @cfr: The absorption is the same; egreg just wanted to post something different using `expl3`...

Comment: @Werner Indeed ;).

Comment: @cfr I used `datenumber`